# Service Based Task Scheduler

Tags: windows, service, scheduled-tasks

I am looking for a task scheduling software that is a service based application that would be able to run script to inform persons of pending event and so fourth via email.

Anyone know of any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

visualcron is a very good tool. But there is a cost attached. It serves the purpose. with many good features.

Answer (score 2):

Why not to use [Windows native task scheduler](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726974.aspx)? Or, if you prefer, his command line counter part, the [schtasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736357%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) command.

Comment: windows native task scheduler would not have worked in the scenerio

Comment: Could you tell us wich scenario is this?

Comment: i wanted the job to run a job based on several criteria (file changes, ftp downloads, etc.), visualcron provided the best option.